# Autosys Watch_File Declaration

Tags: unix, autosys, file-watcher

I have a file watcher job on a Unix box and I'm not sure where to put the wildcard because I'm expecting a datetime stamp appended to the file as such: `filename.txt.{date}.{time}`.

With that being said, at what point do I put the asterisk?

1) `filename.txt*`

OR

2) `filename.txt.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I had to append `.*` again.

So, the full path would be something like this `filename.txt.*.*`